# Play framework 2: reverse routing with parameter in view file syntax

Tags: html, scala, playframework-2.0, playframework-routing

`Item` is a model class and `Items` is a controller class. Now I am trying to use reverse routing with parameter, but it fails. How to fix it?

view:

```
@(item: Item)

<a href="@routes.Items.delete(@item.id)">delete</a>
```

routes:

```
GET     /items/$id<[0-9]+>           controllers.Items.show(id: Long)
GET     /items/add                  controllers.Fruits.addForm()
POST    /items/add                  controllers.Items.add()
DELETE  /items/$id<[0-9]+>           controllers.Fruits.delete(id: Long)
```

error which I get

```
illegal start of simple expression
```

and it points at second `@` character

Comment: Try removing the second `@`.

Comment: @yan, yes it can compile now, thanks. but if I click a generated link then `GET` route is invoked, not `DELETE`.

Comment: It's invoked because your link goes to the GET endpoint. You can't trigger a DELETE from an HTML link.

Comment: @yan, I have updated routes. How to trigger DELETE then? Form and submit button?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Might as well bring the discussion in comments to an actual answer. Your code didn't compile because you had an extra `@` in the argument.

As to why you're not hitting the DELETE end point is because you can't have a regular HTML link trigger a verb other than GET, and you can only submit forms to POST. If you want to invoke delete, you need to use JavaScript. For instance, you can use jQuery's `ajax` method with type set to `"DELETE"`. In your case, you can create an `onclick` handler that in turn sends an ajax request. Also note, not all browsers support the DELETE verb like this.